# Finishing and keeping track of network requests regardless of app focus

Tags: ios, networking, background, afnetworking

I'm building a fairly large social networking application which requires me to upload, retrieve, delete, and update different types of posts (text, image, video, ect). My main question, which seems to answered partially all over SO, is how to design the app, primarily the networking component, so that when a user initiates some API CRUD action such as an upload and then either exits the app or puts it into the background, the API call finishes and returns.

Currently I'm using [MMRecord](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMRecord) to keep my models in Core Data sync and up to date with the data in the backend. The main problem I'm running into as I stated before is how to save, keep track of, and finish any pending network operations once the app is put into the background state or is terminated. MMRecord requires a server class that subclasses MMServer which utilizes an AFHTTPSessionManager object to make requests so I'd like to use that session manager instance to also take care of finishing those requests in the background, just for the sake of encapsulation.

Comment: Can't definitively give an answer without know all the precise details but using beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler will allow your app to keep running for a few minutes after it moves to the background where you can do networking housekeeping.

Comment: Ah ok that's cool. Any advice on how to keep track of networking tasks that haven't finished?

Comment: There's no support for that anywhere built in that I've ever seen. In my programs I might have some BOOL or state variables such as activityXOutstanding which get set to YES when the network activity starts and get set to NO when its completed. Then when the app relaunches it checks these to see if there's anything it tried to do last time it ran but was unable to and so schedules them again.